# Is there a way to make `membar` and `fs_bar` have gradient colors in conky?

Tags: gradient, conky

Is there a way to make `membar` and `fs_bar` have gradient colors in conky? What I exactly need `GREEN` when the usage is low, `YELLOW` when mid-range, and `RED` when there is high usage of memory and disk space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this easily is to write some code in `lua`. If you search you should find many examples, such as [this](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1326214/). It uses a highly parameterable bargraph function.

For something simple in pure conky, you can use `if_match` to change the colour of the *entire bar*, eg:

```
${if_match $memperc>60} ${color red} $else ${color green} $endif ${membar 20,100}
```

You would need to nest another test for a yellow stage, and remove the spaces above if you do not want them to appear in the output.

Comment: I think if_match would be a great idea. Thank you..